# Trouble displaying elements in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to simulate a chat window's Minimize, Maximize and Close functionality using jquery.

I have a parent div with class 'holder', within it I have an iframe and a div (.bar).

For the minimize functionality, I am trying to hide the holder div and iframe while keeping the bar div using replaceWith function.

However, while maximizing, I couldn't show the holder and iframe.

Here is the code -

```
<div class="holder"> 
<iframe id="lsframe" src="http://www.digitech.ch/" width="auto" height="auto">
</iframe>
<div class="bar">Chat<div>
<span class="span1">-</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="span2">&#10005;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery -

```
    $('.span1').on('click', function() {
      if ($(".span1").text() == "-") {
        $(".span1").html('&square;');
        $('.holder').replaceWith(function() {
          return $('.bar', this);
        });
      } else {
        $('#lsframe').show();
        $('.holder').show();
        $('.bar').show();
        $(".span1").text('-');
        //$('.holder').css('visibility', 'visible');                   
      }
    });
    $('.span2').on('click', function() {
      $('#lsframe').fadeOut();
      $('.holder').fadeOut();
      $('.bar').fadeOut();
    });
```

Here is the working model -
https://jsfiddle.net/sathish_panduga/mbwup2t6/2/

I have tried to just hide parent div (holder) and iframe for minimize functionality, but it doesnt work as everything will get hide if I hide parent element.

Could you please point me to the mistake I was doing, how can I achieve it?
Is there any better way to achieve these maximize and minimize functionality?

Comment: The .replaceWith() method removes content from the DOM and inserts new content in its place with a single call.

Comment: This example may give you an idea https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/like-hangout-chat